# Timeout calling stored procedure through SqlConnection

Tags: c#, sql-server-2012, ado.net, sqlconnection

I have 2 separate databases I connect to using linq and EF6. I also run some stored procedures. For speed reasons, I use the old school way of running these using the following method:

```
    public static DataSet ExecuteStoredProcedure(object db, string storedProcedureName, IEnumerable<SqlParameter> parameters)
    {
        string connectionString="";

        if (db is AriaEntities)
        {
            connectionString = ((AriaEntities)db).Database.Connection.ConnectionString;
        }
        else if (db is AMSEntities)
        {
            connectionString = ((AMSEntities)db).Database.Connection.ConnectionString;
        }

        var ds = new DataSet();

        using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandText = storedProcedureName;
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                foreach (var parameter in parameters)
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(parameter);
                }

                using (var adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
                {
                    adapter.Fill(ds);
                }
            }

            conn.Close();
        }

        return ds;
    }
```

I'm passing in the database connection that I'm currently using.

The problem I've got is that when I try to run a stored procedure on the AMSEntities DB context I get a timeout, even though the procedure itself only takes a second to run when run manually in SQL Server. I have execute permissions on the stored procedure and I can access tables in the datacontext with no problem using linq.

Why would the timeout message be happening?

Rob

Comment: I would guess its a network issue. Is your SQL Server instance on a different machine to your application? And does the stored procedure return a large amount of data?

Comment: Is the connection that EF uses open and is there a transaction open? This looks like a distributed deadlock between the two connections,

Comment: I had a closer look at the stored procedure and found that there was a query through to a linked server. I removed that bit and the query wasn't slow any more...

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a `conn.Open();` The DbContext only opens a connection when you SubmitChanges or Enumerate a query.

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't make any difference. It just sits at the Adapter.Fill line before timing out. It works fine for any procedure run in the AriaEntities DBContext.

Comment: Are any of your tables locked? Is this happening for only one stored procedure or all?

Comment: No tables locked at all, I can run the sp fine from SSMS.

Comment: Try setting the SqlCommand.CommandTimeout to a large value to see if the stored proc is just taking a long time to run or you might get an actual exception.

Comment: That was the first thing I tried, I set the timeout to 2 minutes, but the tmeout message still occured after about 20secs.

Comment: I've revisited the timeout settings, if I set the timeout at the command level to 2 minutes, it does actually run the query, but takes about 100 seconds. I don't get why it takes so long when run directly it takes less than a second.

Answer (score 0):

As shown in an above comment, it turned out to be a hidden reference to a linked server in the stored procedure that was causing the slow query execution. Luckily I could remove it as it turned out to be legacy code no longer needed.